# How to print optional value in Swift?

Tags: swift

What's the best way to NSLog an optional value? This is the best I could think of:

```
var s:String? = nil
NSLog("s:%@", s ?? "<nil>")
```

Comment: Now I get it. If you just use `"%@", s` NSLog will crash. I obviously have never used NSLog in swift.

Comment: Why not use `println`?

Comment: @erdekhayser `println` and `NSLog` are not just two equivalent alternatives with `println` being the Swiftier one.  `NSLog` writes a timestamped error to the syslog, `println` just writes text to `stdout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way works if you don't want to indicate it was an optional value in case of a value being present.  But for logging, it's probably best to indicate the optionality since otherwise may lead to confusion. `toString` will keep the indicator:

```
NSLog("%@", toString(s))  // either nil, or Optional("blah")
```

Comment: The correct swift syntax : NSLog("%@", String((s)))

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
println(s ?? "(nil)")
```

Comment: @MatthiasBauch in that case string would not be printed unwrapped. It will be surrounded by "Optional<...>"